# Xamarin Forms - Using GitHub Source Code instead of Nuget Package

Tags: github, xamarin, shiny, nuget

I have a Xamarin Forms Project, and I do use ShinyLib.net Package https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny.

I do have some bugs with Shiny, which I would like to track down and Fix.

How can I make my project use the Source Code from Git instead of the Nuget Packages so I can Debug and Make changes and try to fix some bugs? Shiny already is using .Net MUAI, but it is still compatible with Xamarin.

I tried to Download the Shiny Source Code, and in my Project, I use Add Existing Project, but it shows me that is Incompatible, and it fails when compiling :
Shiny.BluetoothLE is not compatible with netstandard2.1.

Can someone please explain the correct way for me to compile using source code instead of Nuget Package?

Comment: which branch are you using?

Comment: Nice catch. I was using master. 

I switched to 2.6 dev and now I can get it to compile. Now I will try to make my project use the source code instead of the nugged package.

Comment: I almost make it work. 
- I removed the references to the Nuget Packages and the Added the Source Code of Shiny as Existing Project.
- Added Project Reference to this Source

But the Source Generators from Shiny disappeared when I made this. Did I forget something?

Comment: no idea.  I'd post an Issue on their github